# What do I need to do to set up Visual Studio to be able to manipulate an Excel File?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, excel, vba

Let's say I want to find the value of a cell in an Excel file.  In VBA, I would do this:

```
Dim varValue As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
varValue = ws.Range("A1").Value
```

How do I set up a Visual Studio project so I can access and modify an Excel file in C# rather than in VBA?

What references might I need to add?

Does the file need to be open in order to work with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote my own, fairly simple class to extract data from an Excel spreadsheet via C#. You need to include:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
```

Then you can do something like this to get started:

```
Excel.Application excel;
Excel.Workbook workbook;
Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
Excel.Sheets sheets;
Excel.Range range;

excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(workbookName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
sheets = workbook.Worksheets;
...
```

Comment: you can also reference Microsoft Excel Object Library from the COM tab.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Excel automation or a third-party library.

To use Excel automation, you should install the Office PIAs and add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`.   You would then write code to open the file (using the `ApplicationClass` class) and manipulate it.

This approach would use the same object model that you're used to in VBA.  However, since C# 3 does not support optional parameters or weak typing, it will be somewhat annoying.  It would be easier to do it in VB .Net or C# 4 (currently in beta)

---

Excel automation is not suitable for code running in non-interactive context.  There are a number of third-party libraries written entirely in .Net that can read and write Excel files.

In addition, if you only need to manipulate table-like data, you can use OleDb to run SQL statements against Excel files using [this connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel).

You can use [`OleDbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.aspx)s to run `SELECT * FROM [SheetName]`, assuming that the sheet is a table.  You can also select from a named range.  You can get the available tables by calling [`oleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable.aspx) and looking at the `TABLE_NAME` column ion the returned DataTable.

Answer (score 2):

You **do not** have to use interop.

You simply need a reference to...

```
System.Data.OleDb
```

Define a connection string as you would any other data source:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=YourPath;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";";
```

And add some code to query your database:

```
OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection();
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [YourTable]";
objConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
objConnection.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, objConnection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
```

...Then enumerate through your data rows.

Comment: This is only useful if the spreadsheet contains a table-like structure, and you're not interested in formatting.  See my answer.

Comment: Ah -- noted.  Thanks! I'll still leave the answer up as a reference in case someone else does meet those qualifications.

Answer (score 1):

You have to used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
You'll need to use COM Interop. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(VS.80).aspx) a detailed tutorial about how it's done.